# Subscribe to propertyChanged event PostSharp

Tags: mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I have my ViewModel made with PostSharp:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
class ProfileSelectorViewModel
{
    public int Selection { get; set; }

}
```

`Selection` is bound to the selection property of a listbox. How can I subscribe to the change of this property? I want to call a method when `Selection` changes it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event by casting an object of `ProfileSelectorViewModel` class. Because your tooling may complain that the class does not implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` yet, you can use a helper method `Post.Cast<SourceType, TargetType>(SourceType)`.

So if you have an object `obj` of type `ProfileSelectorViewModel` and a method `OnSelectionChanged` handling the change, the subscription looks like this:

```
Post.Cast<ProfileSelectorViewModel,INotifyPropertyChanged>(obj).PropertyChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
```

See http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-add#consuming for details.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code you provided to this: `Post.Cast<ProfileSelectorViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged>(this).PropertyChanged += OnSelectionChanged;`

and put this into the constructor of `ProfileSelectorViewModel`. This really works fine!